# Positioning ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

[image]

Help me guys on the to position the imageview in the left corner of relativelayout. 
When I try to move the imageview there is a margin on the left corner I don't know how to remove that margin.

Comment: add following code in your imageview tag in xml...`android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"`

Comment: you are using padding 55dp in relative layout. you have to remove this because padding will give space inside layout. For more info refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete padding 55dp from relativeLayout

hope this is helpful :)

Comment: how to resize the relativelayout? It's to short for the description I want to put in.

Comment: you had set the attribute layout_height to wrap_content so the relativeLayout will be automatically scalled to textView height